# music play>stop play from began>stop play fro

Tags: android, eclipse

hi i have one button and i want = when is clicked (key_down) music will be play . and then if its playing or not music stop and then play again from the began . like piano app.
its play twice ... why ??? how to fix it??

```
    g1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        MediaPlayer sg1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.b00001);
        @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent) 
        { 
            int action = motionevent.getAction(); 
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
            {         
                       sg1.start();
                     }

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                sg1.seekTo(0);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an onClickListener, not an onTouchListener.  OnTouchListener will tell individual finger actions-  touch up, down, move, etc.  ClickListener will tell you someone clicked a button.

Secondly, since you have 1 button doing two things, you need to save which mode you're currently in and change it on each call to the other mode.  The way you have it coded now will make it start the music, then seek to 0 on every touch down.